Sum of one-sided sub-gaussians is one-sided sub-gaussian
I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, which's right tails, and only their right tails are sub-gaussian.
In particular:
$$\forall t \geq 0:\mathbb{P}(X>t) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right)$$ and
$$\forall t \geq 0:\mathbb{P}(Y>t) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right)$$
I know from Bandit Algorithms by Tor Lattimore and Csaba Szepesvari (Lemma 5.4 c), that the sum of two sub-gaussians is itself sub-gaussian with the new variance proxy $\sigma' = \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}$.
My intuition would be, that the same holds for the right tail of $X+Y$, since a non-subgaussian left tail would only result in lower values, hence a heavier left tail.
Can I thus use the bound
$$\forall t \geq 0:\mathbb{P}(X + Y>t) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)}\right)$$
for the right tail of $X$ and $Y$?
